# APA style not working

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

Reviewing other posts related with APA citation style and parenthetical citation, and packages related with citation style in general, I made a mess, installing too many lines in the code, with `natbib`, `abbrvnat` and `apacite`. Fortunately, I set the code in latex with the functionality of parenthetical citation, which is working correctly, but not with the APA referencing style.

This structure works fine for parenthetical citation:

```
\begin{document}
 \citep{author}
\end{document}
```

The `thesis.tex` document is structured like this:

```
\documentclass{DissertateB5}
\captionsetup{labelfont=\rmdefault, textfont=\rmdefault }

\begin{document}

% incluude each chapter...
\include{chapters/chapter1}

\singlespacing

% the back matter
\clearpage
\bibliography{mendeley}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\end{document}
```

The `dissertateb5.cls` file:

```
(...)
%Import the natbib package and sets a bibliography  and citation styles
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

(...)

%   list an entire bibliography entry inline. Useful for acknowledging when my paper was previously published

\RequirePackage{bibentry} 
    \nobibliography*  

(...)
```

Results in the `bibliography`are:

*Author. Title, Year...*

But should be like APA style:

*AUTHOR (year). Title...*

In this document you can edit the code to try to solve this problem.

https://es.sharelatex.com/project/5847e1b0e473d1cf1e4aee56

[image]

Comment: i think that you should include `\bibliography{mendeley}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
` commands in your preamble (e.g. before `\begin{document}`)and not in your main document

Comment: i did what you mentioned but not working...

Comment: @Yorgos Only the `\bibliographystyle{}` should be in the preamble. `\bibliography{}` must appear in the document!

Comment: @JuanLinares I am not used to sharelatex in spanish ... neither did I use apacite style.  Could you please insert a MWE (MINIMAL working example) to produce the error?

Comment: Above is the MWE improved, with an image the example to edit without registration

Comment: A minor point: In case your bibliography spans more than 1 page, the instruction `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}` should before, not after, `\bibliography{mendeley}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your document class currently loads the `natbib` citation package and specifies `abbrvnat` as the bibliography style. Once one `\bibliographystyle` directive is issued, all later ones are ignored. This happens because LaTeX writes information related to the bibliography style(s) to the aux file; BibTeX then scans the aux file for the applicable style, and it stops scanning once it hits the first such directive.

You should comment out the document class directives

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

and issue the following instructions in the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

Be sure to delete all aux files and to fully recompile your document (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more) to propagate all changes properly.